# How to display acf repeater in tag archive page?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy

I want to show some repeater fields on tag archive page. with this code I can display the simple text fields of acf:

```
$term = get_queried_object();
$meta = get_field('test', $term);
```

but when want to output the acf repeater have no success.

```
$term = get_queried_object();
if (have_rows('faq', $term)) :
    while (have_rows('faq', $term)) : the_row();
        echo get_sub_field('question');
        echo get_sub_field('answer');
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the base code structure for it according to documentation.

```
// Check rows exists.
if( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ):

    // Loop through rows.
    while( have_rows('repeater_field_name') ) : the_row();

        // Load sub field value.
        $sub_value = get_sub_field('sub_field');
        // Do something...

    // End loop.
    endwhile;

// No value.
else :
    // Do something...
endif;
```

Comment: It's the base code and don't working in tag archive page.

Comment: what are the issues with it?